# Giving Ubuntu the same ID as Windows

Tags: wine

I alternate between Windows and Ubuntu, depending on what program I am using. However, there are some pieces of software that I only have one license to (mostly Windows software that I can run on Ubuntu with Wine). For some reason, the software registers that my Ubuntu OS is on a different device than my Windows OS. How do I make my Ubuntu OS identify as the same device that my Windows OS identifies itself as?

Comment: That is proprietary software for you( You are not allowed to do that), and why I only run Free Software https://gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.html. Though it is ok for us to tell you how if we know. Hope some one can help.